# Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.

Tags: javascript, html, json

am a newbie to JSON and i just cant's access to the object data.

this is the code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>ajax </title>


</head>

<body>

    <p id="p"></p>


    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var r = new XMLHttpRequest()
        r.open("GET", "d.json");

        if(r.readyState ===4 && r.status ===200){
        var data = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
        var p = document.getElementById("p");
                p.innerHTML = data.user;

        }
        r.send();   
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

and this is the d.json file

```
{"user":"khaled","age":"20"};
```

i got that error : "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. "

thanks.

Comment: Which line does it point to?

Comment: Your if statement should go into `r.onreadystatechange = function() { /* HERE */ }`

Answer (score 1):

if its a flash url ur dealing with then this link will help

[npe flash](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/error-calling-method-on-npobject/)

else

a general discussion in google comm

[npe google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vhx-api/Q4I5kLo7g2U)